# Are "respect, honour, esteem" synonymous to "lose face"?

Tags: usage, phrases

According to Oxford Dictionaries, "lose face" means:

Be humiliated or come to be less highly respected

And esteem, honour, and respect were given as synonyms. They seem contradictory to me if not outright opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonyms given are for 'face', in the expression 'lose face'. If you lose it, you lose those things.

> Definition of lose face in English:
>
> lose face
>
> PHRASE
>
> Be humiliated or come to be less highly respected.
>
> ‘the code of conduct required that he strike back or lose face’
>
> Synonyms
>
> **respect, honour, esteem, regard, admiration, approbation, acclaim, approval, favour, appreciation, popularity, estimation, veneration,
>   awe, reverence, deference, recognition, prestige, standing, status,
>   dignity, glory, kudos, cachet, image**

[Lose face (Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lose_face)

Comment: But then, is the word "face" synonymous with all those things?

Comment: @VishalGhulati: just as words sometimes have many meanings, they will have different synonyms for different meanings. Also, synonyms are not always identical in meaning, but merely close. I remember when I first got a word processor with a thesaurus built-in, I used to have fun "thesaurus surfing", seeing how far I could get from the original meaning of a word in context.

Comment: Vishal Ghulati - those words are synoyms for 'face' in the expression 'lose face'. 'Face' has more than one meaning.